# Avoid serializing SOAP attributes at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, soap, soap-client

We consume a SOAP service, which has a SaveCustomer function. The SaveCustomer function takes the Customer object listed below, and updates changes, if values are specified in the fields.

Today we found out that if we only want to update say the genderField, we should not send in any other fields, not even as null. Basically we have to avoid serializing.
The problem is that if we send in something like:

```
<Customer>
       <customerIdField>1</customerIdField>
       </emailField>
       <genderField>5</genderField>
</Customer>
```

Then the system will delete the email field. How can we at runtime easily specify whether a field on the object should be included or not in the serialization? I've looked at something like SOAP ignore, but that looks extremely brittle and risky to use. What if new fields are added to the object for example?

At the same time, we actually have to be able to specify a field as null, in case we actually need to delete it from the customer in the system that we consume.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.3752.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.namespace.come/")]
public partial class Customer : CompanyEntity {

    private string customerIdField;

    private string firstNameField;

    private string lastNameField;

    private Address[] addressField;

    private PhoneNumber[] phoneNumberListField;

    private string emailField;

    private EmailBounce emailBounceField;

    private Gender genderField;

    private string sSNField;

    private bool controlStatusField;

    private CustomerProperties propertiesField;

    private CreditCheck creditCheckField;

    private ClubProperties clubPropertiesField;

    private CustomerConsent[] customerConsentField;

    private SalesChannelInfo[] salesChannelInfoListField;
```

Comment: Try to add ``[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]`` on the properties you don't want in the output when they are null  see [DataMemberAttribute.EmitDefaultValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the differences between your project and one of mine, you're missing the "Specified" fields in your data contract class.

Given the wsdl :

```
        <xs:complexType name="setAuthorization">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="action" type="tns:actionType"/>
                <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="role" type="tns:roleType" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
```

You should be generating fields such as ;

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.7.3081.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:si-dmp-habilitations")]
public partial class setAuthorization
{

    private actionType actionField;

    private bool actionFieldSpecified;

    private roleType roleField;

    private bool roleFieldSpecified;
```

It's the "Specified" field that allows you to distinguish between null-delete-any-existing and null-Im-not-changing-this-value.

Check that your WSDL contains the minOccurs="0".  And look at the way you are generating your proxy.  In my example I use SvcUtil with the following syntax :

```
svcutil  /t:code /l:c# /o:"C:\Temp\GeneratedServiceReferences\HabilitationsService.cs" /config:"C:\Temp\GeneratedServiceReferences\HabilitationsService.config" /namespace:*,TLSiKitEditeur.HabilitationService /serializer:Auto /wrapped      wsdl\Habilitations.wsdl
```

I hope that helps